# mobile site not fitting into view correctly

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I can't seem to get this site to format correctly (be "responsive" to mobile) when viewing with mobile devices.

I am using Bootstrap, but when I view from a mobile device, it just looks like a normal desktop is viewing it.  Other sites I have done, it "zooms" in on the text and such to look nice on mobile.

I'm sorry if I'm missing something small here, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TITLE HERE</title>

<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div role="main">
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row address">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h2><?=$content['address']?><br/>
                    <?=$content['city']?> <?=$content['state']?> <?=$content['zip']?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid prop_info">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h3>$<?=number_format($content['price'])?>  | <?=$content['beds']?> Bedrooms  |  <?=$content['baths']?> Bathrooms  | <?=number_format($content['square_feet'])?> Square Feet |  MLS# <?=$content['mls_id']?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row center">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills menu">
                    <li><a href="#">VIDEO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PHOTOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WALKSCORE MAP</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row center">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div id="description-shadow-video-top"></div>
                    <iframe id="vp1HMbXI" title="Video Player" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" src="<?=$content['video_url']?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div id="description-shadow-video"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <?=$content['main_content']?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <img src="/img/foundation/presented-by.png" width="120" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="/img/some_pic.jpg" alt="" name="agentImg" width="90" id="agentImg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row center">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h3><?=$user['first_name']?> <?=$user['last_name']?></h3>
                    <br />
                    <?=$user['company']?><br /><?=$user['address']?>
                    <br />
                    <?=$user['city']?>, <?=$user['state']?> <?=$user['zip']?>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <?=$user['contact_number']?>
                    <br />
                    <a href="mailto:<?=$user['email_address']?>"><?=$user['email_address']?></a>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="span12">
                <a href="http://www.somesite.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/img/the_logo.png" width="210" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are only using `span12` in all the `rows`, which means that they will never get segmented when the viewport changes.  A large part of having a responsive grid layout is breaking the elements of a row into segments so that the row's layout can be adjusted if the viewport falls below certain thresholds.

If the primary `<div>` in every row is `span12` all the content in the row will remain essentially `width=100%` and the content will only scale down as the viewport decreases.

I would suggest avoid using `span12` for every primary `<div>` and spend some time reconsidering the granularity of the content.  See the [Twitter Bootstrap documentation on Scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) for reference.

Comment: Ah ok ... yes that makes sense.  Thanks!  I'll check out those docs a little more in depth now.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this layout, i think it will solve your issue. I removed the row class.**
    
      TITLE HERE

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"> <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script> </head> <body> <div role="main">
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="address">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h2><?=$content['address']?><br/>
                    <?=$content['city']?> <?=$content['state']?> <?=$content['zip']?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid prop_info">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h3>$<?=number_format($content['price'])?>  | <?=$content['beds']?> Bedrooms  |  <?=$content['baths']?> Bathrooms  | <?=number_format($content['square_feet'])?> Square Feet |  MLS# <?=$content['mls_id']?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills menu">
                    <li><a href="#">VIDEO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PHOTOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WALKSCORE MAP</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="center">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div id="description-shadow-video-top"></div>
                    <iframe id="vp1HMbXI" title="Video Player" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" src="<?=$content['video_url']?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div id="description-shadow-video"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

                <div class="span12">
                    <?=$content['main_content']?>
                </div>

        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">

                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <img src="/img/foundation/presented-by.png" width="120" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="/img/some_pic.jpg" alt="" name="agentImg" width="90" id="agentImg" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            <br/>
            <div class="center">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h3><?=$user['first_name']?> <?=$user['last_name']?></h3>
                    <br />
                    <?=$user['company']?><br /><?=$user['address']?>
                    <br />
                    <?=$user['city']?>, <?=$user['state']?> <?=$user['zip']?>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <?=$user['contact_number']?>
                    <br />
                    <a href="mailto:<?=$user['email_address']?>"><?=$user['email_address']?></a>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="span12">
                <a href="http://www.somesite.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/img/the_logo.png" width="210" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer> </div> </body> </html>
```